# What is SerialVersionUID in serialization in java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should I bother about serialVersionUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285793/why-should-i-bother-about-serialversionuid)

What is SerialVersionUID in serialization in java? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a
>   version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during
>   deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized
>   object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with
>   respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the
>   object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the
>   corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an
>   InvalidClassException. A serializable class can declare its own
>   serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named
>   "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long:
>
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;
>
> If a serializable class does not explicitly declare a
>   serialVersionUID, then the serialization runtime will calculate a
>   default serialVersionUID value for that class based on various aspects
>   of the class, as described in the Java(TM) Object Serialization
>   Specification. However, it is strongly recommended that all
>   serializable classes explicitly declare serialVersionUID values, since
>   the default serialVersionUID computation is highly sensitive to class
>   details that may vary depending on compiler implementations, and can
>   thus result in unexpected InvalidClassExceptions during
>   deserialization. Therefore, to guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID
>   value across different java compiler implementations, a serializable
>   class must declare an explicit serialVersionUID value. It is also
>   strongly advised that explicit serialVersionUID declarations use the
>   private modifier where possible, since such declarations apply only to
>   the immediately declaring class--serialVersionUID fields are not
>   useful as inherited members.